# How to create a simple userprompt in clojure

Tags: clojure, stream, flush

Consider this very simple function definition in clojure:

```
(defn prompt []
  (print ">>> ")
  (read-line))
```

My ambition is to let the user enter a string prepended by a prompt-prefix. However, it seems like `read-line` gets executed before the `print` statement. However, by flushing the output stream

```
(defn prompt []
  (print ">>> ")
  (flush)
  (read-line))
```

This function works as intended. Why do I manually have to flush *out* in order for ">>> " to be written out? According to the docs, functions and `do` should execute expressions in order.

Comment: This is usual situation for buffered output for any language. Even C++ has flush function. Buffered output is designed to improve performance by loosing the synchronization between your program flow and output. So if you want to be sure that output is printed you need to flush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are executed in order. But executing a `print` doesn't mean that the given output will be flushed to whatever stream the `*out*` variable is pointing to. As the docs say, the `print` function

> Prints the object(s) to the output stream that is the current value
>   of *out*.

And by default, *out* points to a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) that is generally the target of `System.out`. With the `PrintWriter` instances, flushing isn't enabled by default. Although, you can enable auto-flush via by using [certain constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-) for creating an instance.

Even then, with the `PrintWriter` instances:

> if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `println` instead of `print` to get what you mean:

```
(defn prompt []
  (println ">>> ")
  (read-line))
```

The difference is in the usage of `pr` in the `(source print)` and in `(source println)` `prn` has been used. Take a look at the source codes.